# ¿Cómo eliminar posición?

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tengo una duda que me esta matando, tengo la siguiente función

```js
function buscarmenor (arreglo){
        let guardarapellido = arreglo[0].thing.apellido;
        for (let i = 1; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (arreglo[i].thing.apellido <= guardarapellido){
                guardarapellido = arreglo[i].thing.apellido;
                console.log(arreglo[i].thing.apellido) 
            }
        }
        arreglo.splice
        return guardarapellido;
    }
```

la cual le paso como parámetro un arreglo de JSON y me devuelve por orden alfabético cual es el menor, pero quisiera saber una vez que me encontró el menor como puedo borrar esa posición del arreglo

Comment: Muchas soluciones en [indexof-method-in-an-object-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array).

Comment: me tiras eso y es hablar con la pared jaja no entiendo nada

Comment: una solucion seria copiando a otro arreglo

Comment: Bienvenido. Si bien Stack Snippet se puede usar con JavaScript, este sólo debe usarse con código ejecutable pero el código de la pregunta, estrictamente hablando, no es ejecutable porque al hacer clic en el botón ejecutar no pasa nada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar una variable para guardar la posición del menor valor, luego usas la función splice(), donde le indicas el índice donde empezará a eliminar y cuantos elementos serán eliminados.

```
function buscarmenor (arreglo){
        let guardarapellido = arreglo[0].thing.apellido;
        var pos =0;
        for (let i = 1; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (arreglo[i].thing.apellido <= guardarapellido){
                guardarapellido = arreglo[i].thing.apellido;
                pos = i;
                console.log(arreglo[i].thing.apellido) 
            }
        }
        arreglo.splice(i, 1);
        return guardarapellido;
    }
```